# (Flutter) Posicionamiento de un Container dentro de otro

Tags: flutter

Me gustaría subir los textos ( Bruce miler) y el otro texto ( @Miller ) , ya que no tengo forma de que puedan verse centrados con el icono de su izquierda , se ven muy abajo del container y descentrados respecto al icono,eh quitado los cierres. Un saludo y gracias.

Así se ve actualmente, no se si  hay algún espacio invisible ahí arriba que ocupa el sitio y por eso no me deja ocuparlo.

[image: Aquí os muestro como se ve .].

```
Widget renderPata(){
   return Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 85,
        color:Colors.white,
     child: Padding(  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(),
  child: Row(
      children: [
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 2,
          left: 10,
          right: 10,
        ),
        ),
         Center(
           child: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_default_user.png', width: 70),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container ( 
                height: 30,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 10,
                right: 20,
                ),
              child: Align( 
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
               child:Text('Hace 1 hora',
               style: TextStyle(
                    color: const Color (0xffc4c2bf),
                    fontSize:16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                  ),
                )
              )
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 25,
                  bottom: 3
                  ),
                child: Text(
                  'Bruce Miller',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: const Color (0xff87837e),
                    fontSize:19,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 25,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  '@bmiller',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: const Color (0xffc4c2bf),
                    fontSize:18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
```

Comment: puedes poner todo el método al parecer se cortó

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que trabajaste con un `Column` y este posiciona los `Widget` uno debajo del otro, por tanto el `Text('Hace 1 hora')` ocupaba ese espacio en blanco al que te refieres, solo que estaba acomodado al lado derecho de tu `Column`, lo que hice fue sacar ese **Text('Hace 1 hora')** del `Column` y trabajarlo por separado, y algunos ajustes extras.

```
  Widget renderPata(){
      return Container( width: double.infinity,height: 85, color:Colors.white,
        child: Padding(  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(),
        child: Row(children: [
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2,left: 10,right: 10,),),        
        Center(child: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_default_user.png', width: 70),),        
        Expanded(child: Container(height: double.infinity,
                    child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25,bottom: 3),
                                child: Text( 'Bruce Miller',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: const Color (0xff87837e),
                                      fontSize:19,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                                    ),
                                  ),
                              ),

                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25,),
                                child: Text('@bmiller',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: const Color (0xffc4c2bf),
                                      fontSize:18,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                              ),
                            ]),
                ),
        ),

        Container (height: double.infinity,padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6,right: 20,),
                child:Align( 
                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                        child:Text('Hace 1 hora',
                                style:TextStyle(
                                        color: const Color (0xffc4c2bf),
                                        fontSize:16,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                                      ),
                                  )
                        )
        ),
      ]),
     ),
   );  
  }
```

Comment: Vale si yo pense tmb en trabajarlo por separado en un contenedor ya me imaginaba ejejejee , muchas gracias santiago un saludo.

Comment: Un gusto, saludo!